# i am trying to import class from python file but it show ImportError can not import name what should i do?

Tags: python, oop

In python file there is no circular dependency or any other problem but still it show how `ImportError can not import name from filename`.
there one python fileName

**SQLfirst.py**

```
from dbhelper import Student
st = Student()
print(st.id)
```

another file from i importing class

**dbhelper.py**

```
class Student:
    id = 1

class Student:
    id = 1
```

it just demo file, this is happen very python file

[file where imported class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSSPX.jpg)

[file from i import a class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzFy1.jpg)

[error show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPFac.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 install dbhelper`

Comment: dbhelper.py just python fileName

Comment: you need to import sys and add the py file into sys.path use ```sys.path.append```

Comment: code may be started from different folder and then it uses this folder as `Current Working Directory` (check `os.getcwd()`) and it searchs `dbhelper` in this folder - and it can't find it. You may have to add folder with your code to `sys.path` before importing `dbhelper`. You can get path with code using `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`

Comment: or maybe there is another file with name `dbhelper` but without `Student` and maybe it imports this file - you could check `import dbhelper` and `print( dbhelper.__file__ )`  to see path to file which you import.